# OpenGeo postgres installation not working from command line but works from PGadminIII on fresh install

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ubuntu, boundless-suite

**Problem:**

I just did a default install of opengeo suite (4.1) on Ubuntu 12.04 and followed instructions exactly.  The problem is that I can connect just fine to my postgresql through pgadminIII (1.18.1), but I can't connect on command line.  Has anyone encountered this and if so, how did you fix?

**background:**

As I said above, I am installing opengeo suite (4.1) on a 32bit ubuntu 12.04 installation.  In fact I did it twice, once at home and once at work and I get the same error so it is repeatable:

Basically, i follow all the instructions on the opengeo website. (http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/installation/ubuntu/install.html)

I am sure I am using the 12.04 repository to download software.  I changed the postgres.conf and pg_hba.conf to listen on my machine and accept outside connections and use md5 authentication.

I created a password for the postgres user manually like it instructs.  However, when it comes time to test the command line, it doesn't authenticate. I get the error:

```
~$ psql -U postgres -W 
Password for user postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

The problem is, that I can connect just fine through pgadminIII (1.18.1).  I can run the postgis extension and it creates my postgis database.  I can even edit files I created in QGIS.  But I can't log in via command line so I can't run the shp2pgsql to load any preexisting data.  This is a fresh installation on a machine and, as I mentioned, I tried it on two separate machines (both running ubuntu 12.04 x32).

my pga_hb.conf file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             192.168.0.0/16          md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Show the actual `pg_hba.conf` and explain the specific `postgresql.conf` changes made please. Did you reload/restart PostgreSQL after the change?

Comment: Yes i do reload the service every time after making changes.  postgres.conf i just changed the listen address to the ip of the machine, in this case- Listen_addresses = '192.168.1.101'.  pga_hb.conf added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In psql try using -h localhost

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -W
```

I think psql by default tries to connect on local port (which is using unix sockets) instead of localhost which uses tcpip.  I bet your pg_hba.conf is set to only use peer for local and md5 for localhost.  So opengeo is using the localhost connection while psql is trying to use the local connection.

Comment: <linuxprompt>:~$ psql -h localhost -U postgres -W
Password for user postgres:
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Since you do have the ip change -h to -h 192.168.1.101  .  Normally in postgresql.conf I just set listen to * so if the IP of server changes I don't have to fiddle with the config.  You can also do what Craig suggests and change to md5 for local.  Then your local connection will work fine.

Comment: LR1234567  that was it!   i entered the  ip instead of local host and i got in.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You did not change the `local` line, it's `peer` mode.

If you want to use `md5` auth instead, you must configure `md5` auth, e.g.

```
local   all             all                                     md5
```

instead of your current:

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```